# Word stacking in math mode

Tags: line-breaking

I have this wordy equation and don't have much room in my two-column article style.
I want to stack small expressions with a "partial line break", so as to save room. I figured it out, but it isn't natural at all:

```
\begin{alignat*}{6}
Total\; expected\; loss\; of\; diversity\; = \\
\sum_{\substack{all\\languages}}
        (_{Distinctiveness}^{\;\;\;\;\; Language}) \cdot \Pr(_{\;\;\;\;\:dies}^{Language}) 
\end{alignat*}
```

I feel like a twelve-year-old designing a webpage with non-ending `<br/>` strings

Is there a designated feature for this kind of thing?

[image: The result I have with the code above, which I would like with better code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could misuse the command `\binom{}{}` for this. In order to get a bigger summation sign then, I used the package `relsize` and scaled the sign for two times.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{multline*}
\text{Total expected loss of diversity} =\\
\mathlarger{\mathlarger\sum}_{\substack{\text{all}\\\text{languages}}}
        \binom{\text{Language}}{\text{Distinctiveness}} \cdot \Pr\binom{\text{Language}}{\text{dies}} 
\end{multline*}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Text can be set with `\text` and you can continue using `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{6}
\text{Total expected loss of diversity} = \\
\sum_{\substack{\text{all}\\\text{languages}}}
  \big(\substack{\text{Language}\\\text{Distinctiveness}}\big)
  \cdot
  \Pr\big(\substack{\text{Language}\\\text{dies}}\big)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With using `multline`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\text{Total expected loss of diversity} = \\
\sum_{\substack{\text{all}\\\text{languages}}}
  \big(\substack{\text{Language}\\\text{Distinctiveness}}\big)
  \cdot
  \Pr\big(\substack{\text{Language}\\\text{dies}}\big)
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result multline]

Answer (score 3):

`stackengine` offers a compact syntax in a case like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackunder[8pt]
{Total expected Loss of diversity =}
{$\displaystyle\sum_{\Shortstack{\tiny all \tiny languages}}
\left(\Centerstack{Language Distinctiveness}\right)\cdot
\Pr\left(\Centerstack{Language dies}\right)$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `amsmath` package has plenty of features to cope with this without abusing commands. I'd avoid pseudo-formulas like

> Total expected loss of diversity = `<formula>`

particularly when this would force a split display. But this is not the main concern, do it with `multline*` if you prefer.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
The \emph{total expected loss of diversity} is
\[
\sum_{\substack{\textup{all}\\\textup{languages}}}
  \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
  \textup{Language}\\
  \text{Distinctiveness}
  \end{smallmatrix}\right)
  \cdot
  \Pr\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
     \textup{Language}\\
     \textup{dies}
     \end{smallmatrix}\right)
\]
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Notice `\textup` so the words will be upright even in an italic context.

[image]

Comment: As a refinement, perhaps you could put `\textup{\makebox[0pt]{languages}}` to avoid the big gap after the Sigma?